# Banach Space Condition help

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is $X$ a Banach space, $b\in x$ a vector and $A\in L\left ( x,x \right ) $ an application that checks the condition $\left |A ^{n} \right |< 1$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

(a) show that the equation $x=Ax+b$ has the only solution $x= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\left (A^{k} \right )b$.

thanks for all help

Comment: If the continuous linear operator $A$ has norm $\|A\| < 1$ then $(1-A)$ is invertible (google Neumann series), which gives your answer.

Comment: @YulOtani isn't that pretty much just a geometric series ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis yup, but in this particular case it has this fancy name :) (Actually it involves the subtlety of existing a limit to the series, since $L(X,X)$ is complete).

Answer (score 3):

First note, that $\|A \| < 1$ implies that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \|A^k\| \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|A\|^k = (1- \|A\|)^{-1} < \infty $$ converges. Hence, as $L(X,X)$ is a Banach space, the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k$ converges in $L(X,X)$. Let's call its limit $B$. Then 
\begin{align*}
  B(\mathrm{Id} - A) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k(\mathrm{Id} - A)\\
          &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k - \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^{k+1}\\
          &= \mathrm{Id}.
\end{align*}
Along the same lines, one sees $(\mathrm{Id} - A)B = \mathrm{Id}$, so $B = (\mathrm{Id} - A)^{-1}$. Now note that 
$$ x = Ax + b \iff (\mathrm{Id} - A)x = b \iff x = (\mathrm{Id} - A)^{-1}b. $$

---

EDIT: Note that it is sufficient to have $\|A^n\| < 1$ for **some** $n$, in view of [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404940/help-me-with-this-demonstration-please) this seems to be meant instead of **all** $n$. As: If $\|A^n\| < 1$, and $m \in \mathbb N$ is given, we may write $m = kn + \mu$ with $0 \le \mu < n$ and $k \in \mathbb N$, giving 
$$ \|A^m\| = \|A^{kn + \mu}\| \le \|A^n\|^k \max_{0 \le \mu < n} \|A^\mu\| =: C \|A^n\|^k $$
One now has 
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty \|A^m\| \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty n\|A^n\|^kC = Cn(1 - \|A^n\|)^{-1} < \infty $$
Now continue as above.